# Access denied on c:\

Tags: windows-8

I have made a big mistake on my win 8 Laptop. I set the access privileges for the c:\ only for  Administrator. My main account is administrator but the access is still denied.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Backup and reinstallation will take less time than restoring proper privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Run a 3rd party File Explorer like http://www.freecommander.com as admin, go to the drive properties of C:\, go to the security tab and give users and your account the rights `read`, `read/run` and `list content or directory`.

SYSTEM and admins have full control.

Comment: With the 3rd party Explorer I had also no admin rights. I had to reinstall it.